# I'm tired trying to get subsets

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering, combinatorics, subset

```
t={{a,b},{},{},{},{a},{a,b},{},{a,b,c},{},{b}}
s={{},{a,b,c},{a,b}}
Thread[Subset[t,s]]
```

I'm tired of trying to calculate:

{a,b} [*which is the intersection [{a,b}, {a,b,c}],   All subsets containing {a,b} from the set s*]

{} [*which is the intersection [{},{a,b},{a,b,c}],   the intersection All subsets containing {} from the set s*)

{a,b} [*which is the intersection [{a,b},{a,b,c}],   All subsets containing {a} from the set s*]

{a,b,c} [*which is the intersection [{a,b,c}],   All subsets containing {a,b,c} from the set s*]

{a,b} [*which is the intersection [{a,b},{a,b,c}],   All subsets containing {b} from the set s*]

So, I need to get this set:

```
{{a,b},{},{},{},{a,b},{a,b},{},{a,b,c},{},{a,b}}
```

Comment: This really does not describe what algorithmically you are attempting to do from the inputs `t` and `s`.

Comment: How can i get {{a,b},{},{},{},{a,b},{a,b},{},{a,b,c},{},{a,b}} from t and s?

Answer (score 3):

```
t = {{a, b}, {}, {}, {}, {a}, {a, b}, {}, {a, b, c}, {}, {b}};
s = {{}, {a, b, c}, {a, b}};
```

Let's walk through this one step at a time. What if we just had one set, say `t[[1]]`, and we wanted to find all elements of `s` that contained that given set? We might do this:

```
Select[s, ContainsAll[t[[1]]]]
(* {{a, b, c}, {a, b}} *)
```

Let's try it again for another member of `t`:

```
Select[s, ContainsAll[t[[2]]]]
(* {{}, {a, b, c}, {a, b}} *)
```

One more time, just to be sure:

```
Select[s, ContainsAll[t[[8]]]]
(* {{a, b, c}} *)
```

Next, we need to get the intersection of each of these results:

```
Intersection @@ Select[s, ContainsAll[t[[1]]]]
(* {a, b} *)

Intersection @@ Select[s, ContainsAll[t[[2]]]]
(* {} *)

Intersection @@ Select[s, ContainsAll[t[[8]]]]
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

Seems to be working, so let's bundle it into a function and map over `t`:

```
Intersection @@ Select[s, ContainsAll[#]] & /@ t
(* {{a, b}, {}, {}, {}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {}, {a, b, c}, {}, {a, b}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t = {{a, b}, {}, {}, {}, {a}, {a, b}, {}, {a, b, c}, {}, {b}};
s = {{}, {a, b, c}, {a, b}};

Intersection @@@ ((d |-> Select[s, ContainsAll[#, d] &]) /@ t)

(*or even simpler*)

(d |-> Intersection @@ Select[s, ContainsAll[#, d] &]) /@ t

Clear[s, t]
```

---

```
{{a, b}, {}, {}, {}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {}, {a, b, c}, {}, {a, b}}

{{a, b}, {}, {}, {}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {}, {a, b, c}, {}, {a, b}}
```

Comment: I'm confused about the pipe-arrow notation `|->`. Is that something new?   Because my copy of Mathematica doesn't like it.

Comment: Nevermind: it looks like it was introduced in Ver 12.2, and I have Ver 12.0.

Comment: @march: You can use `Function` instead of `|->` as `Function[d, Intersection @@ Select[s, ContainsAll[#, d] &]] /@ t`

Answer (score 0):

```
 t = {{a, b}, {}, {}, {}, {a}, {a, b}, {}, {a, b, c}, {}, {b}};
 s = {{}, {a, b, c}, {a, b}};

  result = 
   Table[With[{subset = t[[i]]}, 
   If[subset === {}, {}, 
    Intersection @@ Select[s, SubsetQ[#, subset] &]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[t]}]
```